# GAE keeps two instances idling, but why?

Tags: google-app-engine, instance, autoscaling

**Context:** I run a Google App Engine application with automatic scaling. The only regular workload is a cron job that runs every 5 minutes for about 10 seconds and there are usually no other requests to be served. However, GAE still keeps two instances idling in parallel almost all the time.

**Question:** Does anybody have an idea why GAE keeps two idling instances alive? Is it somehow possible to find out what caused a new instance to be spun up?

**Supplemental information:** I am familiar with the article [Scaling dynamic instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_dynamic_instances) and already tried to derive from the application log why new instances are spun up, but couldn't find any clues. My app.yaml looks like this:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
  login: admin

# some more url handlers...

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

builtins:
- deferred: on
```

Comment: Can you show your `app.yaml`?

Comment: As @DanCornilescu mentioned, it'd would be great if you could share your `app.yaml` configuration file. However, as you are using automatic scaling most likely you are using the `min_idle_instances` [element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#min_idle_instances)

Comment: I have added my app.yaml

Comment: This your full `app.yaml`? I cannot see your automatic scaling settings. Could you please update it with the missing parts.

Comment: Well, I did not specify any automatic scaling settings.

Comment: The question is why that (2 idling instances) happens, I would like to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to determinate the exact reason on why the instances are scaling the way they are since there could be other factors involved.

I have tried to reproduced your case by creating a simple job that runs every **5 minutes**. with a simple app.yaml and scaling set by default (automatic scaling) but it stayed with 1 idle instance.

So I tried again, this time i used "[warmup](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests)" settings on the app.yaml (this would prevent the instance to be migrated all at once) and this time the behavior changed: The first hour App engine only kept one instance idle, however, after the hour started to keep 2 instances idle.

**My conclusion** is that since you don't specify a scaling setting, it falls into the default value of "automatic scaling" with all the presets automatic, which means that the scaling is manage by Google. So after a while, Google's algorithm evaluates your application and decides to apply the scaling settings it considers the most efficient.

I believe in your case, the scaling is related to the short times between each job execution and the workload that the instance has to perform at that moment,you can try changing the time between each job execution or setting your own scaling logic.

If you want to set your own scaling, you can configure the "[automatic_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling)" element with "[max_idle_instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#max_idle_instances)" to one (1) if you don't want to have two idle instances.

Example app.yaml:

```
service: my-service
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 1
```

Have in mind that you cannot set "max_idle_instances" to zero, according to the documentation (it only accepts a value between 1-1000 or automatic).The instance spawned by cron job could be staying idle because the job is very frequent (every 5min) so you could try setting "[basic_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#basic_scaling)" with the properties "idle_timeout" and "max_instances".

Example app.yaml:

```
service: my-service
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: B8
basic_scaling:
  idle_timeout: 1m
```

The previous configuration would shut down the spawned instances that are not in use (idle) after 1min.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It does not quite answer my question, though. Why does GAE keep 2 instances idling with almost no load.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my answer, please have in mind that the exact reason on why you have 2 idle instances could depend on other factors around what is being executed during the cron job and the logic Google's algorithm uses to scale automatically your application.